# Confused about 'What she likes I like that.'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, clauses

Let's look at the sentence :

**I like what she likes.**

This is a correct sentence. Here 'what she likes' acts as object of the verb like and it is a noun clause. So we can consider the above sentence as a single sentence with subject, verb and object.

Now let's have a look at another sentence:

**What she likes I like that.**

Is this a correct sentence?
What type of sentence is this?
What type of clauses are there?
What are the object and the subject?
Can I consider it as one single sentence?
I'm totally confused. Please explain it.

Comment: The second example is two sentences juxtaposed. It should be "What she likes is what I like."

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is not standard. It becomes standard if you suppress "that".

- What she likes I like.

If you try to restore the normal order, there is no place for "that". This is an indication that the construction is most probably not correct.

This is a case of fronting the object ([emphatic sentences](https://www.easy-ielts.com/emphatic-sentence-structure/)); so, there is no difference with the first sentence as the parsing is again that which you gave, except for the fronting of the object clause.

> In **spoken and written English** we sometimes want to make a strong contrast with something in a previous statement. We can do this with objects and complements by 'fronting' them (moving them to the front of the clause), which makes theme more emphatic.

*Examples from* Practical English Usage, *Michael Swan, p. 217*

- **What I'm going to do next** I just don't know.
- **How she got the gun through the customs** we never found out.

The second sentence, slightly modified can be correct (mere addition of a comma), as for instance in this dialogue. However, the parsing is different, there is no fronting, the first clause is not the object of "like".

- — What sort of house decoration do  you personally like? I am not asking about your girl-friend…
  — What she likes, I like that.